# horizontal slide-scroll (not scrollbar) if div content overflows

Tags: css

I want to create a div with CSS (preferably without any library) whose contents can be slided right/left on mouse-click if the content of the div is larger than the div width. Like below:

[image]

I tried with overflow-scroll but that gives a scroll-bar which is not what I want. Is it possible to create this with CSS and JavaScript (AngularJS, which I am using in my app) combination, without using any other library? I can use jQuery if it can done using that.

Update: Created a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rishabh1990/dhb71vh8/) after @Shnibble's answer.

```
$("#left").mousedown(function() {
  var y = $("#content").offset();
  $("#content").animate({
    left: 0
  }, function callback() {
      $("#left").fadeOut();
  });

});

$("#right").mousedown(function() {
  var y = $("#content").offset();
  $("#left").show();
  $("#content").animate({
    left: y.left - 200
  });
  $("#info").text(y.left - 100);
});
```

Comment: Refer this site:  http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: The site has something different from I want. It used item hyperlinks to slide to different divs. I won't use any hyperlinks and different divs. Just simple content-slide within same div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I know exactly what you want, do you want the <> arrows to scroll the content or do you want to click+drag the content left and right? Both can be accomplished with JQuery.

The former can be done by having the parent container positioned as `relative` and the `content` within positioned as `absolute`. Then you can use JQuery to alter the `left` offset of the `content` +/- depending on which arrow is clicked.

For the latter, you would do the same setup but check the mouse coordinates on click and apply the difference to the `content` `left` attribute until the mouse button is released.

As for making all of this only happen if the content overflows, you will need to do some checking with JQuery again to measure the width of the `content` and compare it to the parent container and only allow one of the above functions to run if the `content` is wider.

Alternatively, you co use `overflow-x: auto` and then style the scrollbar to fit in with your theme better? See here: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/.

Comment: I would use the <> arrows to scroll the content. Not really familiar with jQuery so would give it a try from scratch. The scrollbar style feature is only available in webkit as per the tutorial you posted.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help